# Vectorising a for loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorise the following function, (`f`)?

I have a vector `x` for which I want to maximise the output value of the function `f` by altering `p`.

But the function is quite slow as it is not vectorised in anyway and was wondering if there was a good way to do so. The idea is to parallelise this in the future, and also potentially use `data.table` to speed it up

my real data is significantly larger...so I'm providing a mock example....

```
# My mock data 
x <- data.frame(x=rep(c(rep(c(0.2,-0.2),4),0.2,0.2,-0.2,0.2),20))

# The function to optimise for
f <- function(p,x){
    # Generate columns before filling
    x$multiplier <- NA
    x$cumulative <- NA

    for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
        # Going through each row systematically
        if(i==1){
            # If first row do a slightly different set of commands
            x[i,'multiplier'] <- 1 * p
            x[i,'cumulative'] <- (x[i,'multiplier'] * x[i,'x']) + 1
        } else {
            # For the rest of the rows carry out these commands
            x[i,'multiplier'] <- x[i-1,'cumulative'] * p
            x[i,'cumulative'] <- (x[i,'multiplier'] * x[i,'x']) + x[i-1,'cumulative']
        }
    }

# output the final row's output for the cumulative column
as.numeric(x[nrow(x),'cumulative'])
}

# Checking the function works by putting in a test value of p = 0.5
f(0.5,x)

# Now optimise the function between the interval of p between 0 and 1
optim.p <- optimise(f=f, interval=c(0,1),x, maximum=TRUE)

# Viewing the output of optim.p
optim.p
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Edit - forgot the first part of the post I had written, putting it in now).

Your problem can be simplified by examining what your function `f` actually *does*. Since I'm lazy, I'm going to write `x[i, 'multiplier']` as m<sub>i</sub>, `x[i, 'cumulative']` as y<sub>i</sub>, and `x[i, 'x']` as x<sub>i</sub>.

Let's look at your equation in `f`. We'll look at the case `i > 1` first:

> m<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i-1</sub> * p
>       y<sub>i</sub> = m<sub>i</sub> * x<sub>i</sub> + y<sub>i-1</sub>

Substitute m_i above:

> y<sub>i</sub> = (y<sub>i-1</sub> * p) * x<sub>i</sub> + y<sub>i-1</sub>  // let's factorise..
>       y<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i-1</sub> * (p * x<sub>i</sub> + 1)

This dispenses with the need to calculate the `multipler` column.

Now looking a little closer at your `i == 1` case, we see that if we put y<sub>0</sub> to 1, the following works out for all i = 1, ..., `nrow(x)`:

> y<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i-1</sub>(px<sub>i</sub> + 1) ---------- (1)

Looking at your function `f`, what you want to calculate is y<sub>n</sub>:

> y<sub>n</sub> = y<sub>n-1</sub>(px<sub>n</sub> + 1)

What happens if we substitute the formula for y<sub>n-1</sub> in the above using (1)?

> y<sub>n</sub> = y<sub>n-2</sub>(px<sub>n-1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>n</sub> + 1)

Now we substitute in y<sub>n-2</sub>'s formula in the above:

> y<sub>n</sub> = y<sub>n-3</sub>(px<sub>n-2</sub> + 1)(px<sub>n-1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>n</sub> + 1)

You get the pattern, right? We substitute all the way down to y<sub>1</sub>:

> y<sub>n</sub> = y<sub>0</sub>(px<sub>1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>2</sub> + 1)...(px<sub>n-1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>n</sub> + 1)

But remember, y<sub>0</sub> is just 1. So, to calculate the value of `f(x, p)`, we just do:

> f(x, p) = (px<sub>1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>2</sub> + 1)...(px<sub>n-1</sub> + 1)(px<sub>n</sub> + 1)

where `n` is `nrow(x)`. That is, calculate `p * x[i, 'x'] + 1` for each `i` and multiply them all together.

---

To multiply a vector of numbers together in R, you use `prod`. So, if `x` was just a vector:

```
f_version2 <- function(p, x) {                                              
    return(prod(p * x + 1))                                                 
}
```

Let's test it on a few things:

```
x <- rep(c(rep(c(0.2,-0.2),4),0.2,0.2,-0.2,0.2),20)                         

> f(0.5, x)                                                                 
[1] 16.56635                                                                
> f_version2(0.5, x)                                                        
[1] 16.56635
```

In summary, sometimes you can achieve speedups simply by analysing the *maths* of the problem, as well as/opposed to the numerical implementation.

Comment: +6.02*10^23 rating for that last sentence alone!